# Intellisense and autocomplete doesn't work in Visual studio code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense, intellicode

Could you provide me help to enable IntelliSense suggestions and autocomplete in Visual studio code 1.30.1? I have installed visual studio Intellicode and path intellisense extensions. Tried:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
"other": true,
"comments": true,
"strings": true
 },
"editor.suggestSelection": "first"
```

In settings.json file, no success

For autocomplete feature installed All autocomplete, but again no success with autocomplete in ‘if’, ‘for’ or anything else. Is it actually possible Intellisense and autocomplete in Visual studio code to work like in Visual studio community?

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete works on type the models have been trained for (common opensource libraries). The most common type you should see recommendations for are strings and data structure types. Being in or out side a control statement does not matter for the recommendations.

[Samples, click on JavaScript for JavaScript sample](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/intellicode/)

If you are still having issues you can report them at: [report issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/intellicode/issues?utm_source=vsmp&utm_medium=ms%20web&utm_campaign=mpdetails).
Provide as much as information possible on what you do and what you expect.